# API routing in ASP.NET to call different API based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to call an existing API, but want to give client specific url.

Example:

```
http://<baseaddress>/controller/action/id
```

This should call

```
http://<baseaddress>/eapi/1.0/Diff-Controller/action/id
```

I have tried `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` but without any success.

Comment: You can write a middleware and when the url matches your condition you can override the request path

Comment: I tried that also, it gives 404

Comment: I can help you troubleshoot your issue, if you're interested contact me

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, you can achieve conditional routing by implementing a custom route constraint or using middleware to intercept incoming requests and redirect them to different APIs based on specific conditions.

This an example using middleware:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomApiMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomApiMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Check the incoming request and modify the URL based on specific conditions
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/controller"))
        {
            string newPath = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/controller", "/eapi/1.0/Diff-Controller");
            context.Request.Path = newPath;
         }

         // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
         await _next(context);
    }
}

public static class CustomApiMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomApiMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomApiMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `[Route]` attribute to your controller:

```
[Route("eapi/1.0/Diff-Controller/[action]")]
public class OtherController : Controller { }
```

Or if it's just for one endpoint, add the `[Route]` to the method:

```
public class OtherController : Controller
{
[Route("eapi/1.0/Diff-Controller/myaction")]
public async Task MyAction() {}
}
```